# Pulling data from a GKLeaderboard

Tags: swift, game-center-leaderboard

Okay, so I have spent a large amount of time searching the internet for help on this to no success, so I would like some help.

I am making a game with SpriteKit, and I have decided to implement my own leaderboard style, rather than the clunky Game Center default. I have managed to log the user into GC, but cannot find the correct (and working) Swift 3 code for pulling information from the leaderboard. I want to pull the top 10 score, along with the current user score (if they aren't already in the top 10). The information I would like from them is position, username and score.

I know this is a fairly simple concept, but every tutorial online either uses the default GC view, or is extremely old/outdated code which no longer works. I just need to know how to pull this information from the leaderboard, then I can process it all myself!

Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: Does the example in https://developer.apple.com/reference/gamekit/gkleaderboard/1503160-loadscores work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I get errors on every line. I'm very new to swift, but is that even swift code? The errors I get are as though Xcode doesn't recognise how the code is written?

Comment: There's a language selector at the top right. For me, Swift is the default, but maybe you get Objective-C as the default for some reason? Try switching the language to Swift.

Comment: I never noticed that before, but yes my default is swift. I have just tried flicking between the two, and their example code stays the same on both. This is why I'm so confused, as all I want to do is pull the data down but I cant find valid Swift code anywhere.

Comment: Selecting Swift does not display Swift code for me - just Objective C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like Apple doesn't have proper example code in Swift, but here's a Swift version loosely based on their Objective-C example:

```
let leaderboard = GKLeaderboard()
leaderboard.playerScope = .global
leaderboard.timeScope = .allTime
leaderboard.identifier = "YourIdentifier"

leaderboard.loadScores { scores, error in
    guard let scores = scores else { return }
    for score in scores {
        print(score.value)
    }
}
```

Note, this is just a translation from Apple's Objective-C code, and I haven't tested it with real data.

Comment: That code has helped me a lot, I have got way further than I did before, one problem. The code you supplied only seems to pull the current user (I have 3 scores saved, but it only prints whoever is logged in), I was wondering if you had any suggestions of how I could get it to print every score from the leaderboard?

Comment: Sorry, I don't actually have any experience with GameKit. That was just a translation of the ObjC code example. Maybe the `range` property in `GKLeaderboard` could get you more than one score?

Comment: i could provide you with a tested answer when I get the score reporting working ... We would be very happy if you take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41051006/testing-gamecenter-leaderboards-in-simulator-do-you-have-to-submit-for-review/41990500#41990500 - because I can't submit a score / get a leaderboard. Thank you!

Comment: Tried this code but keep getting the following error: "The requested operations could not be completed because one or more parameters are invalid."  Anyone know a fix for this?