# Testing GameCenter leaderboards in simulator, do you have to "submit for review"?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I'm reading Apple's documentation for ["Turning On Game Center for the App Version"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectGameCenter_Guide/DistributingGameCenterApps/DistributingGameCenterApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013726-CH26-SW29) and at the end of section "To enable a version of your app for Game Center" step 7 says:

> "Submit for Review"

My app is unpublished and still in development, so I'm reluctant to submit for review. On the other hand my API calls to report/load scores are failing.

Is it required to submit for review in order to test the leaderboard APIs?
What happens after submitting for review?
Can I delete the leaderboard later on?

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question for future visitors, no, you do not need to submit for review.